# Best way to generate xml using jstl

Tags: java, xml, jstl

Very simple question about jstl. Consider Map which return by Controller/Servlet. I would like to generate xml output for client. Should i use standard jstl tags or there is more elegant way to do it ?

Right now i created jsp with this text

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<response>
   <c:forEach var="entry" items="${msg}">
    <${entry.key}> 
      <![CDATA[${entry.value}]]>
     </${entry.key}>
   </c:forEach>
</response>
```

It should work, but i believe there is better way to do it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When my response is XML I usually skip JSTL and use JAXB (i.e. write directly to output stream from servlet/controller).

Comment: If your models are well formed then I would recommend this! Or XStream.

Comment: [xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/) is a very good alternative to the sometimes complex JAXB solutions.

Comment: i think jaxb is good easy enough, i just don't want to add additional dependencies. But this approach is good alternative. At least i don't need to create jsp files

Answer (score 2):

That's how I generate all of my XHTML web pages, and XHTML is XML. You might want to use `<c:out>` or `${fn:escapeXml()}` to escape special XML characters.

Answer (score 1):

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml" prefix="x" %>`

Here is an example from another [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/377513/176818)

or this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/806748/176818)

Comment: Use Kevin's method, it's what i do as well.  However, if you want a jstl tag library.